# Rails project without any SQL code - Every SQL is handled by Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My question is more for practice than a debug issue.
At work, we use a Java-JEE/Oracle solution and the least I can say is we need to perform SQL query, anticipate SQL performances, handle SQL issues like foreign key or orphan line and so on.

So from my point of view, doing SQL is very important. For a new project, we are looking to implement the solution in Ruby on Rails. But most of the tutorial and code I see, seems to nest every Postgres SQL code under Active Record implementation. I have already experienced some similar issue with the Java Hibernate framework and its "no need SQL code." Some production issues were madness, the generated hidden SQL query were not easy to read and there is no deal with index or foreign key.

- Any one can tell me what risk we have to use only Active Record ?
- What is the proper process to avoid most common Ruby/SQL interface issues ?
- When did you need to open your SQL console et type some SQL query ?
- Share a little bit its experience on these points.
- If you have any relevant link dealing with this topic.

Thank you very much !

Comment: So how should an answer look like that you accept it as right answer?

Comment: Oh ! Maybe you can describe your experience with ActiveRecord issue with database or if you think ActiveRecord has everything to avoid typing any SQL query, you can also give me some leads.
According what you have experienced already.
Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use sql.

Either low level, where you receive an array of arrays of values.

Or a little more high level, so you receive objects, with methods like `find_by_sql`.

Or by providing only sql-fragments, for example for the where-clause.

How often you need sql depends on your use case. 
Ruby is about objects, sql is about tables. ActiveRecord handles objects as rows in a table. That works most of the time quite good. All simple queries are handles automatically. You can describe relations between objects, and even joins to retrieve these relations are handled.

For queries with several joins or group_by, it is sometimes easier to write the sql instead of instructing activerecord to build the sql you have in mind.
Also you need to have an eye on what sql is generated, as it is easy to write code that is inefficient, for example by generating many small sql statements.

The official Rails guides about "models" are the most important resource. From sql perspective you should have a look at "Active Record Query Interface"
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

I also done a presentation about rails database optimisation, but it for rails 3.2 and a little out of date (joins are now better handled)
http://meier-online.com/en/2012/08/presentation-rails-database/

Comment: Thanks. I think I have enough leads to work with ^^